# Interactive Zooming into a 2D graphics bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, zooming

I have made a program that reads voltage and current values of some diode curves from an xml file and draws them on screen (Just using plain 2D graphics and some simple commands like DrawCurve and stuff like that).

My main image frame is 800 by 800 pixels (you can see a smaller screenshot down below). Now I want to add a zoom function that when I hover the mouse over this image area, a flying smaller square pops up and zooms in + moves when I move the mouse over this area.

I have no idea how to approach this. Ofcourse I don't ask the full working code but please help me to get closer and closer!

For instance, can I make the zoom to work, without reading the curve data and painting real time? or there is no escape from it? How can I have a hovering image box when I move mouse over the orginal image?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you timed how long `DrawCurve` takes? Perhaps it's fast enough to do in real time. Don't forget, the GDI will clip the drawing primitives to the drawing area. You just need to set up a clipping rectangle as you move the mouse around.

To speed up the redraw, create the main window image (the one you pasted) as an off-screen bitmap, and just `DrawImage` the off-screen version to the window in the paint events. That way you reduce the impact of the `DrawCurve`.

Finally, to get good looking results, overload the `OnPaintBackground` (can't remember the name exactly but it's something like that) so it does nothing (not even call the base class) and do all your painting in the `OnPaint` method using a `BufferedGraphics` object.

*Update*

Your paint function might look like this:

```
OnPaint (...)
{
  the_graphics_object.DrawImage (the background image);
  the_graphics_object.Clip = new Region (new Rectangle (coords relative to mouse position));
  the_graphics_object.TranslateTransform (drawing offset based on mouse position);
  RenderScene (the_graphics_object, scale_factor); // draws grid and curve, etc
  the_graphics_object.DrawRectangle (zoom view rectangle); // draw a frame around the zoomed view
}
```

This will produce a floating 'window' relative to the mouse position.

Comment: Well I think it draws te curves pretty fast (My rough guess is about 10 ms). Can you please explain more about having a clipping rectangular with mouse over event?

Comment: @Sean87: See answer for update. When mouse moves and zoom is enabled, redraw the window.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, cases where redrawing can be time consuming, zooming is usually tackled by providing a "quick but ugly" implementation, alongside the "correct but slow" implementation.  While the zoom operation is actively in progress (say, while the user has a slider clicked, or until a 50ms since the last change in zoom value has happened), you use the quick and ugly mode, so the user can see a preview of what the final image will be.  Once they let go of the zoom slider (or whatever mechanism you provided), you can recalculate the image in detail.  The quick version is usually calculated based on the original image that you are working with.

In your case, you could simply take the original image, work out the bounding box of the new, zoomed image, and scale the relevant part of the original image up to the full image size.  If say 100ms has passed with no change in zoom, recalculate the entire image.

Examples of this kind of functionality are quite widespread: most fractal generators use exactly this technique, and even unrelated things like Google StreetView (which provides a very ugly distorted version of the previous image when you move around, until the actual image has downloaded).